# Confusion about partial derivatives while converting 2-dimensional laplace equation from cartesian to polar

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

So we were given the Laplace equation in 2 dimensions that we had to convert from cartesian to polar coordinates:

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 0,$$
where $u = u(x,y) = \bar{u}(r,\theta)$

So we used the partial differential operator:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \cos(\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial r} - \frac{\sin(\theta)}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$$

We get:

$$\frac{\partial^2 \bar u}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{\partial \bar u}{\partial x}) = \Big(\cos(\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial r} - \frac{\sin(\theta)}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\Big)\Big(\cos(\theta)\frac{\partial \bar u}{\partial r} - \frac{\sin(\theta)}{r}\frac{\partial \bar u}{\partial \theta}\Big)$$

$$\Rightarrow \cos^{2}(\theta)\frac{\partial^2 \bar u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{\sin^{2}(\theta)}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 \bar u}{\partial \theta^2} + \frac{sin^{2}(\theta)}{r}\frac{\partial \bar u}{\partial r} + \frac{2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{r^2}\frac{\partial \bar u}{\partial \theta} - \frac{\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{r}\frac{\partial^2 \bar u}{\partial r \partial \theta} - \frac{\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{r}\frac{\partial^2 \bar u}{\partial \theta \partial r}$$

Now my professor combined the last 2 terms to write (He said that as long as $u = u(x,y)$ and $\bar{u}(r,\theta)$ are "respectable functions" it doesn't matter.

$$\cos^{2}(\theta)\frac{\partial^2 \bar u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{\sin^{2}(\theta)}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 \bar u}{\partial \theta^2} + \frac{sin^{2}(\theta)}{r}\frac{\partial \bar u}{\partial r} + \frac{2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{r^2}\frac{\partial \bar u}{\partial \theta} - \frac{2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{r}\frac{\partial^2 \bar u}{\partial r \partial \theta}$$

So, how can
$$\frac{\partial^2 \bar u}{\partial r \partial \theta} + \frac{\partial^2 \bar u}{\partial \theta \partial r} = 2\frac{\partial^2 \bar u}{\partial r \partial \theta}$$

Because this not invalid if $u(x,y)$ is defined a certain way (which I do not understand - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives). Then how is our operation valid, or in what situations is it valid?

Comment: It is valid if $\bar{u} \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus 0)$, which is equivalent to having $u \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus 0)$.

Comment: Understood! And is this a consequence of Clairaut/Schwarz Theorem?

Comment: Yes. Intuitively, since you can commute difference quotients, you can expect partial derivatives to commute.